# Creating pull request and merging branch on local git server

Tags: git

I have a computer which I host my own git server on. Essentially it acts the same as using github except for the GUI. I can create push/pull to/from the server and clone. Since there is no GUI however, how can I create a pull request for others to view? Is this a limitation of hosting my own git server or is there a way to have a GitHub-like website running locally as well?

Secondly, how do you merge code remotely. Using Github, it is all done remotely on the website after creating a pull request. Since I don't have a GUI to view my code, do I just have to pull in the most recent master branch, merge my branch into master locally, and then push master? A lot of companies restrict direct pushes to the master branch, which forces users to go through a pull request. Will I not be able to do this now or is there a command-line option of merging a branch remotely?

Comment: what git server are you running?

Comment: @LinFelix I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but I followed this tutorial: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that you can't open pull requests in CLI git as it's just a tool to hold various branches of your code. To have that functionality, you can install the free version of [GitLab](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-ce-on-centos-7/) on top of your site if you really need this.

As for your second question about merging, the manual version of it is to pull the latest `master` and remote branch, merge locally, then push the master up. As far as I know, there is no command to do this remotely.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for the help. GitLab is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There is no command for it per say, however github has it's API for that and so might gitlab (including PR/Merge Requests)